# Web view showing background in some activity but not in other?

Tags: android, view, web

I have two activity both are same and there layout almost same. In these web view used. transparent background set to web view. but it appearing in one activity but not in other what may be reasons? Web view showing data from assets folder used Html. what may be reason.I have tried all possible solution .any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please add your code so that we can trace your problem .....

Comment: please set transparent color in your xml for your webview

Answer (score 0):

```
Webview.setBackgroundColor(0);
Webview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.botom_bg);//set your background here
```

try with this two line.